# 2008 Chevy uplander with brake problems

Tags: chevrolet, brakes

I tried to bleed my brakes on my van and I can only bleed my passenger front and driver rear calipers but my other two won't bleed why is that if anyone came help me out I would be grateful

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is it not doing? Why is it it won't bleed? Nothing coming out? or ??

Comment: There is no fluid coming out of the rear passenger caliper or the front driver caliper and I just replaced all four calipers and a new master cylinder

Comment: Why is it you needed to change the calipers in the first place? Also, check your lines front to rear, as in, physically follow them. Look for any crimping of the lines. How are you attempting to bleed them? Take the bleeder screw out completely and ensure there's a way for the fluid to travel through it.

Comment: I've done that and the lines are in good shape and I'm bleeding them by pumping the brake pedal. I've took the screw out all the way n still no fluid coming out

Comment: just how are you bleeding them?  Worst case scenario have a friend help you and have them pump the brakes and then hold the petal down while you open the valve.  When their foot hits the floor, close the valve before they release their foot.  A single air bubble can stop the fluid from gravity-flowing.  

Of course it's also possible you just haven't waited long enough.

Comment: When someone pumps the brakes rock hard I take out the bleeding screw and no fluid comes out and the brake pedal stays hard

Comment: Take the brake line away from the caliper and see if it will bleed from there. It will tell you if it's the caliper or something upstream.